# Vue CLI minifies for production, but how can properties and other definitions also be shortened?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, obfuscation, minify

I looked at an output file (e.g. app.4a7888d9.js) that the Vue CLI generated to see what actually got reduced and I saw that properties declared in the 'data' object, methods declared in the methods object, etc. retain their original name. Same with Vuex state properties.

I'm not trying to obfuscate my code entirely but I do use rather long descriptive names which could benefit of minification. Please don't hate, but an example of a worst case scenario of a property name I have is *scheduledTransactionConditionActiveComponent*

Is there a better way to achieve minification besides what the cli does by default ? If I should use a different package for this, is there one that's proven for vue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vue CLI uses `terser-webpack-plugin` for minification, and [property mangling is disabled by default](https://github.com/terser/terser#minify-options). You could enable it in your Vue config as follows:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.optimization.minimizer('terser').tap(args => {
      const opts = args[0]

      opts.terserOptions.mangle = {
        ...opts.terserOptions.mangle,
        properties: true, // mangle all property names
      }

      return args
    })
  }
}
```

The Terser docs also recommend selective property mangling (e.g., by only applying it to [names that match a `regexp`](https://github.com/terser/terser#mangle-properties-options)). For example, you could configure Terser to only mangle properties that end with an underscore:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.optimization.minimizer('terser').tap(args => {
      const opts = args[0]

      opts.terserOptions.mangle = {
        ...opts.terserOptions.mangle,
        properties: {
          regex: /_$/, // mangle property names that end with "_"
        },
      }

      return args
    })
  }
}
```

Note: Although this works well for data props, this mangling does not work for component names (i.e., property names under `components`).

Comment: Thanks @tony19. After adding the vue.config.js and the first code example, I get `TypeError: config.optimization.minimizer(...).tap is not a function`.

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong: I placed the `vue.config.js` in the root path where my `package.json` file is. I made sure that `terser-webpack-plugin` exists in my `node_modules` folder. When adding a `console.log(config.optimization)` before calling the function the output shows that minimizer is a function `minimizer: [Function]` ... any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: That's odd. I was able to run that config in a default Vue CLI project on macOS (running `@vue/cli v4.3.1`). What's the output of `vue inspect | grep terser`?

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure if it's because my project setup is over a year old and I need to update something, but I got it to work using a slightly different approach and setting the minimizer using a `new TerserPlugin({terserOptions: {...} })` object. Another problem I'm facing now is that after compiling the project, the minimized version causes new errors, which I need to look further into. At first glance it looks like that the new generated naming causes issues when calling certain methods. So I will try to fix my project config to get ur regex example to work to better control the renaming.